# jquery function won't work for button tag

Tags: jquery, function, button

I made a button using the `<button>` tag and ID'ed it. I wrote a jQuery function calling on that button by its ID but the function won't work. If I switch the `<button>` tag to `<a>`, it works. Is there a way to make the button functional?

Here's my code (the button makes the div it's in fadeout and switch to another page but it won't even fadeout).

```
<div id="page">
     <button id="button1">button1</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#button1").click(function(){
      $("#page").fadeout(1000)
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `fadeout(1000)` should be `fadeOut(1000)`. Works fine when I fixed that http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FmjMA/

Comment: It works fine for me, but note that I've changed `fadeout` to `fadeOut`: http://jsfiddle.net/DZX3E/

Comment: works for me, too... Is there something else you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: oh sorry, that lower case o was just a typo. i'm also using the reveal.js plugin. would this have something to with that?

Answer (score -2):

Couple of things:

Wrap the JS in a doc.ready call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#button1").click(function(){
          $("#page").fadeOut(1000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

This will ensure that the code is only run when all the elements have loaded. If you click the button before the script has loaded then nothing will happen. [More info here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Also, make sure the case is correct. `fadeOut()` is a function, `fadeout()` isn't. If you open developer tools (e.g. in Chrome press F12) it'll notify you if you have a JS error, which will give you a starting point to tracking down what's wrong with your code.

Comment: This is unlikely to be the problem since according to the question "if I switch the `<button>` tag to `<a>` it works".

Comment: OP already had the script block after the button, so that script should not have to be within document ready.

Comment: no, it doesn't need to be in doc.ready, but it's best practice to do so. It also quite clearly doesn't work if you change button to a: http://jsfiddle.net/5KHaH/ since the fadeOut function is the wrong case, as I mentioned in the answer which you didn't bother to read